# Intellij IDEA ssh tunnel to datasource

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, ssh, datasource

I'm trying to view my remote database running on digital ocean droplet as data source in Intellij IDEA.

[ssh tunnel settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll59o.png)

[general database settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5n2W.png)

I accessed the database from Sequel Pro through ssh so I believe it is set correctly on the server side.

When I test the connection it says: Connection refused by foreign host.

What have I done wrong?
The ip is correct and the passwords and ssh keys as well, I'm certain of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually the ssh port is 22, if you haven't it customized.

If this tunnel is successful, you can connect against your database with the given port.

Check your screenshot. It shows 3306 for the ssh tunnel.